# What is the right way to translate ''I am the master of my fate, I am the captain of my soul'' in latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I have been looking now for a while the right translation of these sentences in latin;

***I am the master of my fate,
I am the captain of my soul.***

---

I have found three different answers but not sure which one is the correct one ?

**Dominus fortunae meus sum,
Gubernator sum animae meus.**

```
     OR
```

**Dominus fortunae meae sum,
Capitaneus animae meae sum.**

```
     OR
```

**Fati mei sum dominus,
animae meae sum imperator**

Could someone tell are the translations wrong ? What is the right way to translate these sentences ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Context matters. In what regards is the person in question "master of his own fate?" For example, he could be able to decide where he goes, what he does, or whether he lives at all, or other combinations of the three. Knowing who this phrase applies to will help make sure we're all translating properly.

Comment: @Nickimite The original context of those words is [this poem](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/51642/invictus) (and the context of the poem is that the author suffered from severe medical problems throughout his life), though of course I do not know in which context the Latin translation is intended to be applied.